# Unable to figure out how ModelForm is rendered using generic UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how the ModelForm is instantiated when I'm using generic `UpdateView`.

I've gone through the django source code and looked into `UpdateView` and relevant `Form` classes but I can't see any line of code where we are explicitly passing `instance` to the object of `ModelForm` class.

For example, say we have `PostForm` as a `ModelForm` then we would have written :

```
form = PostForm(instance=Post.object.get(pk=pk))
```

to render the form from the models object.

I can't see similar code in the django source code and can't figure out how the generic `ModelForm` is getting populated in case of `UpdateView`
i.e. how the `self.instance` attribute of my form is getting instantiated when I submit data after POSTing the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `instance` attribute of `ModelForm` is instantiated in `get_form_kwargs()` defined in `ModelFormMixin`

For detailed explanation see below :

The `UpdateView` view inherits `SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseUpdateView`

`BaseUpdateView` further inherits `ModelFormMixin` and `ProcessFormView`
It also defines the `get` and `post` methods that are called via dispatch
These `get` and `post` methods sets the `object` attribute as the current model object. Below is the code snippet from django docs :

```
class BaseUpdateView(ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    """
    Base view for updating an existing object.

    Using this base class requires subclassing to provide a response mixin.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The get and post methods also call the parent's get and post method i.e. get and post defined in `ProcessFormView`

**During GET request**
The `get` method defined in `ProcessFormView` calls the `get_context_data()` overridden under `FormMixin` which further invokes `get_form()` to return an instance of the form to be used in the view.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Insert the form into the context dict.
    """
    if 'form' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
    return super(FormMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

`get_form()` calls `get_form_kwargs()` which lies in `ModelFormMixin` as well as `FormMixin` but since the `ModelFormMixin` inherits from `FormMixin`, the method defined in `ModelFormMixin` overrides the one defined in `FormMixin`. This `get_form_kwargs()` method first calls the super/parent's method and then sets the `instance` attribute of the form to the current model object i.e `self.object` (or simply `object`).
Code snippet from the docs below :

```
def get_form_kwargs(self): #defined in ModelFormMixin class
    """
    Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
    """
    kwargs = super(ModelFormMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
    if hasattr(self, 'object'):
        kwargs.update({'instance': self.object})
    return kwargs
```

The form is then rendered using the model object's attributes

**During POST request :**
As mentioned earlier (see first code snippet), just like `get()`, `post()` method also sets the `object` attribute to the current model object i.e. `self.object=self.get_object()`.  ( get_object() is inherited from `SingleObjectMixin` class )
It then calls `post` method of `ProcessFormView`i.e. parent class which creates the instance of `form` using `get_form()` method.  (Just like get_context_method was doing in case of `get` request)
`get_form()` calls the `get_form_kwargs` which further sets the `instance` attribute of the form to the `self.object` instantiated in first `post` method call.
Code snippet below :

```
class ProcessFormView(View):
"""
A mixin that renders a form on GET and processes it on POST.
"""
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.
    """
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then checked for validity.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)

# PUT is a valid HTTP verb for creating (with a known URL) or editing an
# object, note that browsers only support POST for now.
def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(*args, **kwargs)
```

Next, the form is validated against basic constraints and this is done by calling `form.is_valid()` method which is inherited from `BaseForm` class.
This is a very important step because at this point, the `instance` object's attributes are updated to the data POSTed in the form.

This all is achieved via following stack of calls :

`form.is_valid()` calls -> `errors` property -> which calls `full_clean()` -> `_clean_fields()` -> `_clean_form()` -> `_post_clean()`
`_post_clean()` constructs the `instance` from `POST` data by calling `construct_instance_method`

To understand these functions better read the `BaseForm` class for `is_valid()` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/forms/forms.py#L65) and `BaseModelForm` class for `_post_clean()` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/forms/models.py#L289)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the method
[`FormMixin.get_form_kwargs()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs).

Here is the source from the Github [repo](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L35):

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    ...
    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        kwargs.update({
            'data': self.request.POST,
            'files': self.request.FILES,
        })
    return kwargs
```

As you can see, if the request is POST, the data from POST and FILES
are returned from this method, which in turn is used to instanciate the form, as you can see in this second snippet below from the same [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L29):

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    ...
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

Comment: @Raif: There are two cases :

Comment: Looking at the code again and reading through the accepted answer: you are correct, my answer isn't right.